# Meteor async method call

Tags: meteor

I am very new to meteor and I have a method in `Meteor.methods` like :

```
sendStory(story) {

    HTTP.call("GET", "https://offline-news-api.herokuapp.com/stories", function(error, response){
      if(error){
        console.log("error")
      }else{
        console.log(response)
        var story = story
        return story
      }
    })
  }
```

and then I am calling this on my cliet like:

```
Meteor.call('sendStory', this.story, function(res){
        console.log("some story")
        console.log(res)
      })
```

Here it is not printing the `res` value it is giving `undefined` and the api call is made at last..

How can I make api call first and then go to `callback` from api

Thank you ..

Answer (score 1):

Well,

dont use the callback for http call like this:

```
sendStory(story) {
 var story = HTTP.call("GET", "https://offline-news-api.herokuapp.com/stories");
 return story;
}
```

refer here to [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call)

You cannot return from a callback since Meteor methods run within fibers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Future:

```
sendStory(story) {

    Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
    var apiFuture = new Future();

    HTTP.call("GET", "https://offline-news-api.herokuapp.com/stories", function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.error("Error: ", error);
            apiFuture.throw(error);
        }else{
            console.log("Response: ", response);
            apiFuture.return(response);
        }
    });

    return apiFuture.wait();
}
```

and on the client:

```
Meteor.call('sendStory', this.story, function(err, res){
    console.log("some story");
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Great! A response from the API: ", res);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [guns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1794539/guns) mentioned, you are returning undefined from server method. The method doesn't wait for the asynchronous function to terminate. Instead it returns.

In the server, I always go with synchronous approach.